# xcode 10.2.1 "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64"

Tags: ios, swift, build, cocos2d-x

I have a game that I created in cocos2d-x 3.15 on my pc and it works fine. Then I moved my project to mac, switched the platform to iOS, and tried to build it for iOS 9.0 and for a iphone XR Device, now I'm getting the error "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64" for couple days. the error log is this:

```
"_UIApplicationMain", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RootViewController in RootViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_RootViewController in RootViewController.o
  "CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()", referenced from:
      TRMusicSound::isMusicPlay() in TRMusicSound.o
      TRMusicSound::loadingGameMusic() in TRMusicSound.o
      TRMusicSound::loadingGameSound(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in TRMusicSound.o
      TRMusicSound::setMusicStutas(bool) in TRMusicSound.o
      TRMusicSound::playHeadMusic() in TRMusicSound.o
      TRMusicSound::playGameMusic() in TRMusicSound.o
      TRMusicSound::playGetReadySound() in TRMusicSound.o
      ...
  "cocos2d::Node::init()", referenced from:
      vtable for BaseNode in BaseNode.o
  "cocos2d::ui::Widget::addTouchEventListener(std::__1::function<void (cocos2d::Ref*, cocos2d::ui::Widget::TouchEventType)> const&)", referenced from:
      BaseNode::resetWidgetTouchEvent(char const*) in BaseNode.o
  "cocos2d::Vec2::ZERO", referenced from:
      BaseNode::init(cocos2d::Node*, bool) in BaseNode.o
      BaseLayer::LoadUIFile(char const*, bool) in BaseLayer.o
  "cocos2d::CSLoader::createNode(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      BaseNode::create(char const*, bool) in BaseNode.o
  "cocos2d::ui::Button::loadTextureDisabled(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, cocos2d::ui::Widget::TextureResType)", referenced from:
      UIGameLayer::updateQetButton() in UIGameLayer.o
  "cocos2d::ui::LoadingBar::setPercent(float)", referenced from:
      UIGameLayer::updateRoleBlood() in UIGameLayer.o
      UIGameLayer::updateRoleMagic() in UIGameLayer.o
      UIGameLayer::setBossBlood(float) in UIGameLayer.o
      UIGameLayer::setBossBlood(float)::$_1::operator()() const in UIGameLayer.o
  "cocos2d::ProgressTimer::create(cocos2d::Sprite*)", referenced from:
      UIGameLayer::initBossCD() in UIGameLayer.o
  "cocos2d::ProgressTimer::setType(cocos2d::ProgressTimer::Type)", referenced from:
      UIGameLayer::initBossCD() in UIGameLayer.o
  "cocos2d::ui::PageView::setCurrentPageIndex(long)", referenced from:
      UISelectScene::updateRolePage() in UISelectScene.o
  "cocos2d::ui::Button::loadTexturePressed(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, cocos2d::ui::Widget::TextureResType)", referenced from:
      UISelectScene::updateButtonStutas(cocos2d::Node*, int) in UISelectScene.o
      UIGameLayer::initHead() in UIGameLayer.o
      UIGameLayer::updateQetButton() in UIGameLayer.o
  "typeinfo for cocos2d::ui::TextBMFont", referenced from:
      UISelectScene::updateCoins() in UISelectScene.o
      UIGameLayer::initPropCount() in UIGameLayer.o
      UIGameLayer::initCombo() in UIGameLayer.o
      UIGameLayer::updateDistance() in UIGameLayer.o
      UIShopLayer::updateCoins() in UIShopLayer.o
      UIResultLayer::initLayerUI() in UIResultLayer.o
.....
```

I searched everywhere and tried everything i could, but still had no luck. Until now I have tried:

1. Changing architectures(armv7 and arm64 and standard architectures)
2. Changing "Build active architecture only" to no
3. Changing "Dead code stripping" to no
4. Adding $(inherited) to "Other Linker Flags"
5. Adding "Security" and "SystemConfiguration" Frameworks to Build Phases
6. Disabling "bitcode" and enabling "Preserve Private External Symbols"

Comment: can you please try using lower ios version devices ? because iPhone XR contain 12.0 OS that's why may be you are getting that error.

Comment: I have to build it for ios9.0...I can't lower ios version..

Comment: we have now 12.0 so you need to add latest version than olderversion

Comment: try to update the pod using in terminal  `sudo gem install cocoapods` after process done. goto folder dictionary and try pod install again

Comment: i did not use pod to add coscos project,so it won't help..thanks...

Comment: Thank you..I have fix the problem by adding more lib in the project one by one..